# The random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=...$

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the joint density $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=
\left\{\begin{matrix}e^{-y}, \mbox{ } 0\leq x \leq y \le \infty
\\ 0,  \mbox{   otherwise}\end{matrix}\right.$$
Evaluate the conditional expectation $E[X|y]$.

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly. Please let me know if something is off in my solution. Thanks for reading.

**My solution:**

I'm not sure if my approach is correct since $f_{Y}(y)$ turns out to be an infinite number. Also in line 4, is the domain correct?

$$E[X|y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X|Y}(x|y)dx.$$

$$f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}.$$

$$f_{Y}(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx$$

$$= \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y}dx = e^{-y}\int_{0}^{\infty}1dx $$

$$=e^{-y}\left [ x \right]\Big|_0^\infty $$

$$ = ??? $$

Thanks in advance for reading this and responding!

Comment: To avoid mistakes like integrating from $0$ to $\infty$ instead of $0$ to $y$ for finding $f_Y(y)$, you should always write the support of the joint density where the indicator functions come in handy.

Comment: Please avoid multiplying **structural** duplicates. If you can answer the other question, surely you can answer the present one, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest rewriting the joint density using the indicator function $\mathbf1_{a\in A}$, which equals $1$ if $a\in A$ and equals $0$ otherwise.

So you have

\begin{align}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=e^{-y}\mathbf1_{0<x<y}&=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{y}\mathbf1_{0<x<y}\,ye^{-y}\mathbf1_{y>0}
\\\\e^{-(y-x)}\mathbf1_{y>x}\,e^{-x}\mathbf1_{x>0}\end{cases}
\end{align}

We have expressed the joint density in two different ways, in each case $f_{X,Y}$ factors as the product of a conditional density and a marginal density.

From the first case, $$f_{X\mid Y=y}(x)=\frac{1}{y}\mathbf1_{0<x<y}$$

And from the second case, $$f_{Y\mid X=x}(y)=e^{-(y-x)}\mathbf1_{y>x}$$

At this point you can calculate the conditional means simply from definition. Or you might identify $X\mid Y$ as having a uniform distribution over $(0,Y)$ and $Y\mid X$ as having a shifted exponential distribution (i.e. $[Y\mid X]-X$ has an exponential distribution with mean $1$), from which the expectations follow easily.

Answer (score 1):

For $\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]$:
$$
f_Y(y) = \int_{[0, y]}e^{-y}dx=e^{-y}(y-0)=ye^{-y},
$$
 $Y \sim \mathcal{G}amma(2,1)$. Hence, 
$$
f_{X|Y}(x|y)= \frac{e^{-y}}{ye^{-y}} = 1/y, \quad x\in(0,y),
$$
namely, $X|Y=y$ is Uniform on $[0,y]$.

Comment: I'm failing to see how you brought in the gamma. Do you mind explaining that bit? thanks.

Comment: $f_{Gamma(2,1)}(y) = 1^2/1! e^{-1y}y^{2-1}$.

Comment: Do you mind explaining it a different way.

Comment: I have not learned it this way. Is it possible to show this using:

Comment: through continuing the equation $$f_{Y|X}(y|x) = ...$$

Comment: @beepboopbeepboop Note that the integration of $x$ is on $[0,y]$ as $0 < x < y$, the comment about Gamma is just by identifying the density. You can ignore it. It does not help to find the expectation.

Comment: through continuing the equation $$f_{Y|X}(y|x) = ...$$ , I get that $$E[X|y] = \frac{1}{y} \int_{0}^{y}xdx =\frac{y}{2}$$. I got this from following the first two lines' formulas.

Comment: @V.Vancak Yes, I understand the domain of x now, thanks. And the to the latter, okay!

Comment: But as I said in my previous comment, I am getting $\frac{y}{2}$

Comment: @beepboopbeepboop Exactly. If $X|Y=y \sim U[0,y]$, then $\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]=y/2$.